# Facing issues in downloading a particular attachment from gmail through Python

Tags: python, download, gmail, attachment

I have the below piece of code which works fine for downloading CSV files. But I'm trying to download a file without any extension name where this is failing. The `part.get_filename()` is not fetching anything and hence the code is failing with error `NameError: name 'fileName' is not defined`. The search is working correctly and identifying the particular email.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import os
import imaplib
import email
#from email.header import decode_header
#import webbrowser
import os
import datetime
import time
import glob
import shutil

today = datetime.date.today()
yday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=5)

# account credentials
username = "xyz@gmail.com"
with open(r'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\Google sheet key\gmail_app_pwd.txt','r') as pwd:
   password=pwd.read()


# create an IMAP4 class with SSL 
mailBox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
# authenticate
mailBox.login(username, password)


svdir = r'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\Work'


boxList = mailBox.list()
# print(boxList)

mailBox.select()

searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Mailer as on ' + str(yday) +'")'


result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
ids = data[0]
# list of uids
id_list = ids.split()

i = len(id_list)
#x=0
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = id_list[x]

    # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    result, email_data = mailBox.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]

    # converts byte literal to string removing b''
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # downloading attachments
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(svdir, fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()

    subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]
    print('Downloaded "{file}" from email titled "{subject}" with UID {uid}.'.format(file=fileName, subject=subject, uid=latest_email_uid.decode('utf-8')))

mailBox.close()
mailBox.logout()
```

Comment: If there is no filename, what do you want this code to do?

Comment: A filename is there but without any extension. The file is just called "datapoints", after download is complete I can rename it to "datapoints.csv" and use. I can't get the sender to make changes (if lack of extension is causing this issue)

Comment: If there is no filename *extension*, what do you want this code to do?

Comment: Download the file, rename it to proper extension and then use it for whatever purposes

Comment: What part(s) of this are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?  (Any why not just save it to the appropriate filename-with-extension in the first place, and avoid needing to rename it?)

Comment: Thanks, you made me think through what was going wrong, will update solution

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.  (Yes, it is perfectly OK to answer your own question!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I removed the checks. Updated code:

```
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = id_list[x]

    # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    result, email_data = mailBox.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]

    # converts byte literal to string removing b''
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # downloading attachments
    for part in email_message.walk():
        **fileName = "file.csv"**
        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(svdir, fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```